# get_header() on new page fatal error

Tags: theme-development

I'm building theme and using this link in navigation bar to `about.php` page.

```
<li><a href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/about.php">אודות</a></li>
```

Now I can't understand why but when I enter `about.php` I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_header()
> in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\photography\about.php:2
> Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
> D:\XAMPP\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\photography\about.php on
> line 2

About.php page

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I'm not sure if I need to define something in my functions.php file.

How can I load properly `get_header();` function in about.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [the theme template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/). There is no "about.php" file and you should not link to any of the theme (PHP) files directly. Instead, you would create a theme file such as "page-about.php" and create its content in wp-admin as a Page with the slug "about," and WordPress will process that Editor content within the PHP file to create the final visible page. If you have pretty permalinks enabled you will want to link to "/about/" instead of the theme file, but because you have named the PHP file "page-about," WP will apply it to a Page with the slug "about."

Comment: Can you redirect me so I can read more about the template hierarchy? I understand, I added through wordpress dashboard new page but It doesn't show up in my theme folder. also shows me the same page as index.php

Comment: @YotamDahan The [Template Hierarchy page](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) is a good starting point.

Comment: @PatJ Changed my link to this `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/index.php?page_id=15` and still having the same error, my page name is page-about.php now

Comment: You should not be linking to PHP files inside your theme, ever. If you want to output a link to a page with PHP you should use `get_the_permalink( $id )`, where `$id` is the page ID. In your case though you should be using WordPress [navigation menus](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/navigation-menus/) to output these links, rather than hardcoding them like this.

Comment: Right, with standard permalinks you would just link to "https://example.com/?page_id=15" or whatever URL it shows as the Permalink in the Editor.

Answer (score -2):

`get_header()` is part of wordpress core.

Seems your wordpress files damaged or installed incorrect. Try to reinstall it.
Probably you should move `D:\XAMPP\htdocs\wordpress` into `D:\XAMPP\htdocs\`